# Watching multiple files with inotify in perl

Tags: perl, file-io, inotify

I need to watch multiple files in Perl, and I am using [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Linux%3a%3aInotify2). However I am encountering an issue in that the first file being watched needs to be modified and hit, then the second, then the first etc etc

For example if the second file is changed before the first, it will not trigger out, or if the first is triggered twice in a row without the second being triggered in between.

This is the section of code I am using which is having this issue.

```
my $inotify = new Linux::Inotify2;
my $inotify2 = new Linux::Inotify2;
$inotify->watch ("/tmp/rules.txt", IN_MODIFY);
$inotify2->watch ("/tmp/csvrules.out", IN_MODIFY);

while () {
  my @events = $inotify->read;
  unless (@events > 0){
    print "read error: $!";
    last ;
  }

  foreach $mask (@events) {
    printf "mask\t%d\n", $mask;

    open (WWWRULES, "/tmp/rules.txt");

    my @lines = <WWWRULES>;
    foreach $line (@lines) {
      @things = split(/,/, $line);
      addrule(@things[0], @things[1], @things[2], @things[3], trim(@things[4]));
      print "PRINTING: @things[0], @things[1], @things[2], @things[3], @things[4]";
      close (WWWRULES);
      open (WWWRULES, ">/tmp/rules.txt");
      close (WWWRULES);
    }
  }

  my @events2 = $inotify2->read;
  unless (@events2 > 0){
    print "read error: $!";
    last ;
  }
  foreach $mask (@events) {
    printf "mask\t%d\n", $mask;
    open (SNORTRULES, "/tmp/csvrules.out");

    my @lines2 = <SNORTRULES>;
    foreach $line2 (@lines2) {
      @things2 = split(/,/, $line2);
      addrule("INPUT", @things2[0], @things2[1], @things2[2], trim(@things2[3]));
      print "PRINTING: INPUT, @things2[0], @things2[1], @things2[2], @things2[3]";

      close (SNORTRULES);
      open (SNORTRULES, ">/tmp/csvrules.out");
      close (SNORTRULES);
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like to be watching 3 files but as I cannot get 2 working it seems a little pointless at this stage.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A single inotify object can handle any number of watches.  That's one of the advantages of inotify over the older and now obsolete dnotify.  So you should be saying:

```
my $inotify = Linux::Inotify2->new;
$inotify->watch("/tmp/rules.txt", IN_MODIFY);
$inotify->watch("/tmp/csvrules.out", IN_MODIFY);
```

Then you can see which watch was triggered by checking the `fullname` property of the event object:

```
while () {
  my @events = $inotify->read;
  unless (@events > 0){
    print "read error: $!";
    last ;
  }

  foreach my $event (@events) {
    print $event->fullname . " was modified\n" if $event->IN_MODIFY;
  }
}
```

The big problem is that your code is modifying the same files that you're watching for modifications.  When `/tmp/rules.txt` is modified, you open it, read it, and then truncate it, which triggers another modification notice, starting the whole process over again.  In general, this is hard to solve without race conditions, but in your case, you should be able to just check for an empty file (`next if -z $event->fullname`).

Comment: Actually, there is a limit on the number of watches by handle. This limit is set in /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing checks in serial on something that you want to happen in parallel.  You're either going to want to fork a separate process, use threading, or integrate it in with a POE object.

Another option, which may or may not work for your application, is to set your tempdir to something more specific and keep all the files you're working on in there, then just watch the directory as a whole, which would then only require 1 inotify object, if i'm reading this right. (I haven't done anything with this module in particular but I have a pretty good idea of how it works by hooking syscalls to the file system).

Comment: If I watch a directory, can I determine which file within that directory is modified so I can act depending on which one has been changed?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that you should be able to.  Unless I'm mistaken, IN_ACCESS events should still be raised for a file in the directory.